# How can you clear a List?

Tags: lotusscript

I have a List that I'd like to reuse but I haven't been able to figure out how to clear it of it's previous entries.

```
dim x list as string, i as integer
for i = 1 to 4
 x("a"+cstr(i)) = "blue"+cstr(i)
 x("b" +cstr(i)) = "green"+cstr(i)

  <do some stuff>
  <Before I loop back around, I want to clear 'x' so it does not contain the previous entries>
next
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Erase x ' delete whole list
Erase x(el) ' delete element
```